# Skipped error during the execution of trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I create a trigger on database event LOGON , to avoid someone without permission login to the database by mistake. When the host name start with C, it need to be reject to connect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SYS"."LOGIN_RJ" AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE
HOST_NAME VARCHAR2(128):=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST');
BEGIN
if (HOST_NAME like 'C%') then
    raise_application_error(-20000,'host login denied');
end if;
END;
```

It's useful for most user account, but specific user can still login to the database without any ORA error.

1. While the user logon to database successfully, I found the database generate alert log as above:

```
> Skipped error 604 during the execution of SYS.LOGIN_RJ
> 
> dbkedDefDump(): Starting a non-incident diagnostic dump (flags=0x0, level=0, mask=0x0)
> Error Stack Dump -----
> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
> ORA-20000: host login denied
> ORA-06512: at line 6
```

2. I tried to grant/revoke the roles and found that DBA or IMP_FULL_DATABASE role will affect the above trigger. When the user is granted IMP_FULL_DATABASE role , the trigger will not raise application error.

Is there any other method to restrict user login without revoke the role privilege(IMP_FULL_DATABASE or DBA)?

Comment: [Related DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6709/847) explaining why the trigger is affected by those roles.

Comment: Check to see if the user has the `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` priv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Administrative accounts can be blocked from logging in to an Oracle database by raising an ORA-600 error in a logon trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYS.LOGIN_RJ AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  --Only an ORA-600 error can stop logons for users with either
  --"ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER" or "ALTER ANY TRIGGER".
  --The ORA-600 also generates an alert log entry and may warn an admin.
  INTERNAL_EXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( INTERNAL_EXCEPTION, -600 );

  HOST_NAME VARCHAR2(128):= SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST');
BEGIN
  IF HOST_NAME LIKE 'C%' THEN
    RAISE INTERNAL_EXCEPTION;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

***WARNING***

Be very careful with this solution for the following reasons:

1. You never want to be in a situation where you prevent all administrators from logging in.
2. ORA-600 errors are resource-intensive errors that generate a trace file. And it's possible that your database is monitored to automatically report on such errors. This solution might spam a DBA. In the worst case, if an automated system triggers this error a thousand times, your operating system may grow in unexpected places and create a denial-of-service attack. Talk with your DBAs before you implement this trigger.
3. The HOST variable can be spoofed, because Oracle has to depend on 3rd party database connectors to provide this information. Depending on your JDBC software, it may be possible for an application to change its host name. In practice, not many people are going to do this, but the ability to spoof means your solution is not 100% bullet proof.

I've used code like this before, and it can work and be useful. But you should be aware of the limitations and use a better security mechanism if one is available.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments above, DBAs can't (edit: usually) be blocked from connecting using logon trigger errors.

If you need to block certain hostnames from connecting, editing your firewall rules is the most powerful option. Oracle also has limited options to block IPs and hostnames in Listener using [sqlnet.ora configuration parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.html#GUID-A649AB38-37DA-4033-BDC6-9D8E6E417C32).

Comment: There *is* a way to block DBA access with triggers (see my answer), but your suggestion to use sqlnet.ora parameters is probably a much better solution.